# Spring Cloud Stream Function support does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream

I trying to use Spring Cloud Stream with functions as that described in this [topic](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-stream.adoc#spring-cloud-function-support). But it does not work.

My function:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> consumer() {
        return s -> System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

And I push message. to the `consumer-in-0` channel via producer that made with `@Output` annotation:

```
pulic interface Source {
    @Output("source")
    MessageChannel producer();
}

source.producer().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello").build());
```

My yaml channels configuration:

```
spring:
    cloud:
        function:
            definition: consumer
        stream:
            bindings:
                source:
                    destination: consumer-in-0
```

If I use consumer via `@Input` configuration - everything ok.
Also in rabbitmq manager I see that producer is working and sending messages, but consumer does not consuming them.
Help me please somebody.

P.S. I also use Spring WebFlux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot mix `EnableBinding` and functional model in the same application. If you are putting both producer and consumer in the same application, you might want to convert your producer using a `Supplier`. For e.g.

```
@Bean
public Supplier<String> supplier() {
  return () -> MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello").build();

}
```

Then,

```
spring:
    cloud:
        function:
            definition: supplier;consumer
        stream:
            bindings:
                supplier-out-0:
                    destination: consumer-in-0
```

Comment: It looks like you're right, it works, thank you very much. Now I tried sending the payload via rabbit manager and my `Consumer` is working. However, how can I run(execute) my `Supplier` from code? I tried `supplier().get()` but it does not work((
Or how can I send message to the topic programmatically?

Comment: If its a `Supplier` bean as I suggested and you add it to `spring.cloud.function.definition`, it should be invoked automatically by Spring Cloud Stream. By default, the supplier will be triggered every second, but you can control that using https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/DefaultPollerProperties.java

Comment: It really sucks that you can't mix them... guess we'll be stuck w/ the deprecated annotations forever. Too big of a technical debt pill to swallow to refactor all of these & the related int tests in one swing.